# Oracle objects deployment using Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: oracle, azure-devops, procedure

I have a requirement to automate deployment to different environment(dev, stage and prod) using Azure devops. I am not able to find a task for the same. Azure devops has task for SQLServer database deploy, MySql Database deploy but not for the Oracle database deploy. 
I am very new in Azure devops. Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

For this issue, Red Gate has [a set of deployment tools for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/), but integrated in Azure Devops is the [SQL Change Automation](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-change-automation/) extension, which is only applicable to SQL Server database.

So AFAIK, there is currently no task for Oracle database deploy. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. You could also vote the suggestion ticket and share your comment there, so product team would provide the updates if they view it.

As a workaround , you could try to use the PowerShell on Remote machine task to deploy your Oracle changes and place them in an Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline without having to install an extension from the Marketplace. For details ,please refer to this [blog](https://arjanvanbekkum.github.io/blog/2019/07/18/Using-Azure-DevOps-Server-to-deploy-Oracle-objects).